# How to avoid delete the Temp files using java?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a simple code to generate the temp files and store the some values(I don't want to store the files in normal storage area)
In future, I want to use that file and get the data from that file (its not a problem if the user manually delete the files).
But I don't want to delete the files automatically. when read this link, I get some information, generally temp files not deleted 
when you explicitly call `deleteOnExit()` but when my JVM finish the work temp file deleted automatically.

```
//create a temp file
File temp = File.createTempFile("demo_", ".txt");
String path = temp.getParent();

//count the file which names starts with "demo"
File f = new File(path);
File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.startsWith("demo") && name.endsWith(".txt");
}
});

// Print count array elements
    System.out.println("Length : " + matchingFiles.length + " ");
```

Here I never call the  `deleteOnExit()` (but file delete automtically)OR JVM automatically delete the file? By the way its deleted automatically if is it possible 
to avoid deleting the file? or any other ways to do my requirement?

Comment: I tried your code on Windows and the file is not deleted after the program exits.  What operating system are you running this on?  Does the OS have a temp-file cleanup process running continuously?

Comment: windows 10 . . okay i will check that

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct directory?

Comment: actually test with both directories  . .

Answer (score 1):

File.createTempFile only creates files with unique names, other than that they are just regular files. They are not deleted automatically. It is explained in File.createTempFile API: *This method provides only part of a temporary-file facility. To arrange for a file created by this method to be deleted automatically, use the deleteOnExit method*

Comment: Thanks for expatiation, its nice. so file will be deleted autoamatically right??/if i want to want to create the undeleted temp files means how to dot that?

Comment: no, by default it wil not be deleted on exit. only if you explicitly call deleteOnExit

Comment: BUT how i never call deleteOnExit () method in my code still my files deleted. why?How??

Comment: Are you sure it is deleted? Temp files are created in user's temp folder. Add System.out.println(temp); to your code and see where it is created

Comment: Yes its Deleted automatically that the problem. when i check the count its always 1. because old files are deleted automatically. i try to get the pcath using temp.getAbsolutePath() its show "temp/filename" . not like this C://user/appdata/bla bla/

Comment: try to create it in current folder File temp = File.createTempFile("demo_", ".txt", new File(".")); and check

Comment: its show like this path is : /./demo_4066797627896775972.txt

 but no more file in current dir

Comment: you ran your app once and you got 1 temp file and it is not deleted. Run app once more and you will see another temp file.

Comment: no i always get count is 1 . . it does not increment

Comment: ***WARNING*** Do not use `deleteOnExit()` in a system designed to remain active for long periods of time -- i.e. a web application.  Files to be deleted are stored in a `Map`, and if the application never exits the map will eventually fill up all available memory and crash the system.  This is a known restriction of `deleteOnExit()`.

Comment: @JimGarrison okay i don't use that method in my code but now after execute finished my temp file deleted ?is there is any reason ? how to avoid delete the files?